# Notice: Undefined variable: led_nem in C:\xampp\htdocs\online\Online Task Management System\task_mem.php on line 71

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to run this query

```
$SQL = " SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '$led_nem'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tsk = $db_field['group_task'];
}
```

I get this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: led_nem in C:\xampp\htdocs\online\Online
>   Task Management System\task_mem.php on line 71

Comment: Once check the `$led_nem`... once print it and check whether it has a value or not..

Answer (score 0):

Test if the variable `$led_nem` exists before you use it:

```
if (isset($led_nem)) {
    $SQL = " SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '$led_nem'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tsk = $db_field['group_task'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if (isset($led_nem)) {
$SQL = " SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '".$led_nem."'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tsk = $db_field['group_task'];
}
}
```